# Copy dropped file to other dropzones before submit

Tags: dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js.

I have a table of items, where each row has a dropzone.
I have autoProcessQueue: false, a submit-all button, and a sending event.
It is working fine - I can drop files and the button uploads them.

I want to be able to drag & drop a file into the first row, and then click a copy button to copy this file to all the other dropzones, so that when I click submit-all I get the same file attached to each item.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Having looked around at javascript solutions to copy a FileUpload, I think the functionality is deliberately blocked for security reasons.

So I decided on a server-side solution.  My Copy button records in the form the item IDs it should copy to.  On the server after uploading the file once, I loop through the "copy to" item IDs and upload the file repeatedly to the others.